# Rails: Using AJAX to delete a form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, form-for

I have a nested form where an workout has many exercises, and I'm trying to allow the user to delete and add exercises to the form without having to submit the form.

```
<%= form_for(@workout) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %></br>

    <%= f.fields_for :workout_exercises do |workout_exercise| %>
        <fieldset>
            <%= workout_exercise.text_field :name %>    
            <%= workout_exercise.hidden_field :_destroy %>
            <%= link_to "Remove Exercise", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
               ##This is what I want to do ##
            <%= link_to 'Remove Exercise', set, remote: true, class: "remove_fields delete", method: :delete %>
        </fieldset> 
  <% end %>
```

Right now I can make the fields fade out, but to save the change to the DB I need to click the "update workout" button at the bottom of the form. I want the change to take effect as soon as the "Remove Exercise" button is pressed, otherwise, users will think an element has been deleted when it's actually just been hidden.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend the [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) for this. You can add [events before and after a nested fieldset is inserted](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#callbacks-upon-insert-and-remove-of-items) as needed.